# Firebase App check suddenly getting error invalid token

Tags: ios, flutter, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-app-check

I am integrating AppCheck with realtime database in flutter. As per documentation its working perfectly. i tested for both platforms (iOS & Android). My token is expiring TTL duration (7 days) with enforced option. now i am checking in iOS platform not able to read real time database. suddenly getting error.

> Firebase Database connection was forcefully killed by the server.  Will not attempt reconnect. Reason: Invalid AppCheck token

also tried re-install app & Re-genrate token many times but not able to read data.
verify token with debug toke in firebase console.